# Weird location of point with longitude latitude

Tags: ios, mapkit, latitude-longitude, point

I am trying to add a point to the map.

I get this with:

```
- (void)plotCrimePositions:(NSData *)responseData {
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in _mapView.annotations) {
        [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
    }

    NSDictionary *root = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *data = [root objectForKey:@"features"];
    NSLog(@"features: %@", data );

    for (NSDictionary *dic in data) {
        NSDictionary *geometry = [dic objectForKey:@"geometry"];
        // Do what you want..
        NSNumber *latitude = [geometry objectForKey:@"x"];
        NSNumber *longitude = [geometry objectForKey:@"y"];
        NSString *crimeDescription = @"test";
        NSString *address = @"banaan";

        NSLog(@"latitude: %@", latitude );
        NSLog(@"longitude: %@", longitude );
        NSLog(@"error: %@", crimeDescription );
        NSLog(@"error: %@", address );

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
        coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;
        NSLog(@"latitude2: %f", coordinate.latitude );
        NSLog(@"longitude2: %f", coordinate.longitude );


        MyLocation *annotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:crimeDescription address:address coordinate:coordinate] ;
        [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}
```

I get this as NSLog:

```
2012-11-14 10:57:02.404 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] Response: {"displayFieldName":"Gecontroleerd","fieldAliases":{"Gecontroleerd":"Gecontroleerd"},"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint","spatialReference":{"wkid":4326},"fields":[{"name":"Gecontroleerd","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"Gecontroleerd","length":255}],"features":[{"attributes":{"Gecontroleerd":"Ja"},"geometry":{"x":5.9680979652859065,"y":52.507071127790766}}]}
2012-11-14 10:57:02.421 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] features: (
        {
        attributes =         {
            Gecontroleerd = Ja;
        };
        geometry =         {
            x = "5.968097965285907";
            y = "52.50707112779077";
        };
    }
)
2012-11-14 10:57:02.423 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] latitude: 5.968097965285907
2012-11-14 10:57:02.424 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] longitude: 52.50707112779077
2012-11-14 10:57:02.425 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] error: test
2012-11-14 10:57:02.426 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] error: banaan
2012-11-14 10:57:02.427 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] latitude2: 5.968098
2012-11-14 10:57:02.437 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] longitude2: 52.507071
```

But it should be around here: 
[image: Holland]

But the map shows it here:
[image: Africa somewhere]

It says that the location 
 2012-11-14 10:57:02.427 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] latitude2: 5.968098
    2012-11-14 10:57:02.437 ArrestPlotter[9254:907] longitude2: 52.507071

Should be in holland.

Does anyone know what im doing wrong or has the same problem?
Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Could it be because i used an tutorial from the USA and i used this value

```
#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the longitude and latitude the wrong way round:

```
NSNumber *latitude = [geometry objectForKey:@"x"];
NSNumber *longitude = [geometry objectForKey:@"y"];
```

should be:

```
NSNumber *latitude = [geometry objectForKey:@"y"];
NSNumber *longitude = [geometry objectForKey:@"x"];
```

Comment: Don't! We've all made similar mistakes...amazing how another pair of eyes can help

Answer (score 2):

Try searching Google Maps.  That is where those coordinates are.

You are inputting them in reverse.  If you reverse the two numbers, then you are in Holland.